# Boolean in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have this json object that has a boolean data type. I'm trying to look or learn on how i set my boolean as a response for my retrofit builder. So basically i have this "status" that indicates true or false in my json object. How do i set the that status and declare that if the status is true the text color will be green or else it will be false. I'm still a beginner with this bear with me pls.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: i do it says it cannot resolve method 'settext'(boolean)

Comment: You should run app, its right sometimes android studio gives these types of editor error and see logcat.

Comment: same error occurred when i run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `response.body().getSoftware()[i].status` is a boolean type. You can't use boolean as an input parameter in `setText` method - the signature of this method allows you to pass String or Int(string resource id).
To reach your goal try setting text color using this variable:

```
if (response.body().getSoftware()[i].status) {
   softwareStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
   softwareStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
softwareStatus.setText(response.body().getSoftware()[i].status.toString())
//or use softwareStatus.setText("" + response.body().getSoftware()[i].status) if status is primitive boolean and not object Boolean
```

Also, don't forget to set some text if it's not set in your XML layout.

UPD (to have all statuses in one coloured string):

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getSoftware(); i++) {
        String textToSet = "" + response.body().getSoftware()[i].status;
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(textToSet);
        ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(response.body().getSoftware()[i].status ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
        spannable.setSpan(fcs, 0, textToSet.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        softwareStatus.append(spannable);
        softwareStatus.append("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: no i mean my status are set from my json objects. basically i need that boolean type to get a response and display that status such as the true or false based on the status of the software to my text view and set their text color.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. If you need status text "true" with green color in case of `response.body().getSoftware()[i].status` is true, and text "false" with red color in opposite case, then add `softwareStatus.setText(response.body().getSoftware()[i].status.toString())`

Comment: i thought the way around that i will be setting up the text of true or false to the text view. one more question tho. in this line of `softwareStatus.setText("" + response.body().getSoftware()[i].status)` is there any chance where it could be shown all instead of one by one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. What input do you have and what output you want to see? I can assume, that you want to display all statuses in on text view appended?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want to display all the status on a single text view just like the code that i have for the hardware and software name.

Answer (score 0):

`it says it cannot resolve method 'settext'(boolean)`

You are getting this error because you are trying to pass a `boolean` value parameter to `setText` method, such signature of `setText` doesn't exist, hence it is giving you this error. You can read about `setText` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)).

If you need to display true/false in your TextView you can do like,

```
setText(someBoolean + "");
```

or if you need to show something else based on true/false then you should check value in if condition and then do whatever you need to.

It seems like you are getting this error here

```
softwareStatus.setText(response.body().getSoftware()[i].status);
```

You can try like,

```
softwareStatus.setText(response.body().getSoftware()[i].status + "");
```

Comment: I just need to display the true/false in my textview so I used setText(someBoolean + " ") but someboolean is giving me an error. it says it cannot resolve method..

Comment: @YenBico Okay, glad it helped. Here at StackOverflow you should mark an answer accepted and upvote it if it works for you. It helps other visitors to know what worked for you, if they are facing same issue.